# no he podido con las funciones en php quiero se ejecute la funcion set_borrar no hace nada donde la ponga da error como se realzaria de la mejor forma

Tags: php, web, msql

Quiero borrar por medio poo pero no realiza nada da error no se como formularlo
trae le Id bien, realiza hereda la conexion,la funcion que borre no se ejecuta, quiero realizar algo seguro y bueno que funcione :(
no he podido con las funciones en php quiero se ejecute la funcion set_borrar no hace nada donde la ponga da error como se realzaria de la mejor forma.

```
 <?php
  ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
  error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);

  require ("conexion.php");  

  $Id =$_GET['Id'];
   
  echo "el id es: ". $Id;

  class Borrar extends Conexion{
  

  public function Borrar(){
    parent:: __construct();
   }
  
  function set_borrar(&$Id){

   if(isset ($Id)){

   echo "entra al if de afirmacion";

  $consulta= $this->conexion_db->query("DELETE FROM user_model WHERE ID='$Id'");
    
    header("Location:panel.php");  
    
    $this->conexion_db=null;     
   }else{
    echo "falla al tratar de borrar";
  }
   
     }    
   }    

  }
  set_borrar();

  ?>
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! que error?

Answer (score 1):

Tu código está plagado de errores: de sintaxis, de concepto, de lógica. Y no es seguro como pretendes. Cuando se trata de la base de datos, la seguridad en este caso consiste en usar consultas preparadas.

Cuando puedas te aconsejo que te leas con calma [todo lo relacionado a la POO en PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.php), así como un buen libro o artículo sobre Programación Orientada a Objetos, en el que se traten los conceptos fundamentales con las propiedades de un objeto, los métodos, la *herencia*, el *poliformismo*, etc.

En tu código no aplicas bien nada de eso. Voy a intentar aclararte cada cosa.

#### Los métodos están mal.

##### El constructor

Metes el constructor de la clase dentro de un método llamado `Borrar()` ¿Vienes de Java quizá o de otro lenguaje que hace cosas similares? En PHP (después de la versión 4, y vamos por la 8) no es así. Los constructores de clases se escriben directamente:

```
class Borrar {
    function __construct() {
        //Configurar alguna propiedad del objeto  
    }
}
```

Y, suelen ponerse cuando quieres inicializar propiedades del objeto. Si no es el caso, puedes incluso omitir el constructor en la escritura de la clase, lo cual no significa que no lo tenga. El mismo queda implícito.

Una llamada a `parent:: __construct();` no tiene sentido ahí. Esa llamada se hace cuando, en la herencia, tienes que pasar al padre aquellas propiedades que no son del hijo. Lee sobre la herencia y revisa los ejemplos de código.

#### Los métodos *setter*

Los métodos *setter* se usan para cambiar propiedades del objeto una vez creada la instancia del mismo. Imagina que el valor de un objeto cambia a lo largo de su ciclo de vida. Usas el *setter* para hacer ese cambio.

Tú tienes un método `set_borrar` que no tiene ningún sentido. Lo usas para pasar el ID de la fila que se va a borrar (además lo pasas por referencia al usar `&`, sin entenderse por qué). En ese caso, lo lógico sería pasarlo en el constructor de la clase.

Vamos a hacer que tu clase empiece a parecerse a POO:

```
class Borrar {
    private $id;
    public function __construct($ID) {
        $this->id=$ID
    }

    public function set_id($ID) {
        $this->id=$ID
    }
}
```

#### Errores de lógica y/o de concepto

Una clase escrita así está capada. Las clases deben ser pensadas por lo general como moldes para construir cosas de tal tipo, sin importar el contexto en que se vaya a usar esas cosas.

Si en una clase tú pones salida por pantalla, redirecciones, inicios de sesión, etc. **Esa clase no te servirá en contextos donde no se admitan salidas por pantalla, redirecciones, etc**. Te aconsejo que mantengas tus clases lo más limpias posible y que traslades toda esa lógica fuera de ellas.

Lo mismo pasa con la validación que haces aquí: `if(isset ($Id)){` Malll, muy mal. Debes validar antes de crear la instancia de la clase, no después. O estarás creando algo inútilmente.

#### Herencia mal entendida

En POO la *herencia* es algo metafísico, se trata del *ser* de las cosas. Si no aplicas esto, terminarás usando la herencia para algo *funcional*, lo cual es un error gravísimo, y lo cometes en tu código. Dices: *quiero borrar datos, y como necesito la conexión para eso, escribo una clase que se llama `Borrar` y hago que herede de `Conexion`*.

Veamos algunos ejemplos de herencia:

```
class Maestro extends Persona { //... }
class Autor   extends Persona { //... }

class Camion  extends Vehiculo { //... }
class Autobus extends Vehiculo { //... }
class Coche   extends Vehiculo { //... }

class Perro extends Animal { //... }
class Vaca  extends Animal { //... }
class Gato  extends Animal { //... }
```

Un `Maestro` y un `Autor` **son** una `Persona`, un `Camion`, un `Autobus` y un `Coche` **son** un `Vehiculo`.

Tu clase es un despropósito en ese sentido, porque **un `Borrar` NO es una `Conexion`**, y por tanto NO debe extender de ella. Haces un uso utilitario de la herencia que es un gravísimo error en POO.

Es más, tu clase `Borrar` **debería ser un método de alguna clase**. En POO, todo lo que sea un **verbo** debería ser un método y las clases tienen nombres de **sustantivos**.

#### Una falsa idea de seguridad

Lo que hace un código seguro no escribir POO, aunque apliques bien todos los conceptos de la misma.

La seguridad va del saneamiento de los datos que se mostrarán en pantalla, de usar consultas preparadas para incluir datos externos en la consulta, etc.

Un código bien escrito desde el punto de vista de la POO que haga esto no es seguro:

```
$consulta= $this->conexion_db->query("DELETE FROM user_model WHERE ID='$Id'");
```

El problema es que un usuario mal intencionado manipularía el valor de `$Id` para inyectar código a través de la variable `$Id`. Para prevenir eso debes escribir una consulta preparada. Dado que no sabemos si usas PDO o mysqli, no puedo decirte cómo hacerlo.

#### Conclusión

Sabiendo que desde el punto de la herencia esta clase es un despropósito, te dejo algo donde se aplique todo lo dicho, para que lo veas de forma global.

Esta sería nuestra clase, totalmente limpia. En lugar de `Borrar` la llamaremos  `Crud`, pensando en una clase que sirva para crear, leer, actualizar o borrar datos de la base de datos.

En los métodos no hemos puesto `$this->conexion_db=null;` Conviene que la clase `Conexion` tenga un método `close()` que puedas invocar. Así, podrás usar la misma instancia de `Crud` para llamar a varios de sus métodos. Pensemos en un contexto donde quieras borrar cierto ID, actualizar otro, podrás llamar a `deleteBy()` y a `updateById()` con la misma instancia. Si destruyes la conexión dentro del método eso no será posible. Aunque habría que revisar cómo se gestiona la conexión en la clase `Conexion`.

```
class Crud extends Conexion
{
    private $id;
    public function __construct($id) 
    {
        $this->id=$id;
    }
    
    public function deleteById($table,$column,$id)
    {
        /*
            Aquí debes usar consulta preparada
            Debes borrar la fila y devolver el total de filas borradas
            Eso hace la clase utilizable en cualquier contexto 
        */
        $sql="DELETE FROM $table WHERE $column=?";
        $consulta= $this->conexion_db->prepare($sql);
        // Debes hacer el bind de $id según uses PDO o mysqli
        // Debes ejecutar la consulta con execute()
        // Debes retornar el total de filas afectadas
    }
    
    /*
        Esta misma clase servirá para actualizar registros 
    */
    public function updateById($table,$columns,$values)
    {
        //$sql=TODO  
        $consulta= $this->conexion_db->prepare($sql);
        // Debes hacer el bind de $this->id según uses PDO o mysqli
        // Debes ejecutar la consulta con execute()
        // Debes retornar el total de filas afectadas       
    }
}
```

Ahora hagamos un **uso contextual** de esa clase. Cuando escribes una clase, la idea es **poder usarla** donde sea. Aquí se requiere un inicio de sesión, pero puede que en otra parte no. La clase queda independiente de eso...

Cosas como la validación del id se hacen en el contexto, NO dentro de la clase.

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);

require ("conexion.php");  

$id =$_GET['Id'] ?? NULL;
if ($id) 
{
    //Asumimos que la clase está en un archivo llamado crud.php
    require ("crud.php");  
    //Pasamos el $id al constructor
    $crud=new Crud($id);
    //Lógica contextual de borrado
    if ($crud->deleteById("user_model","ID",$id) > 0)
    {
        header("Location:panel.php");
    }
    else 
    {
        echo "falla al tratar de borrar";
    }
}
else 
{
    echo "ID no válido";
}
```